# CKEditor - getting the default toolbar array BACK prior to instantiation

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have not found this on the CKEditor documentation and am reasonably sure it can be accomplished.  I know that if you explicitly pass `toolbar:` to CKEditor when instantiating an editor, you can control the toolbar config.

What I would like to do is first GET the default toolbar and remove buttons based on some user requirements.  How would I fetch the CKEDITOR toolbar array *first*?  Thanks!

(NOTE: I thought it might be found in `CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Full` like in this link [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar) but that shows as *undefined*; I'm using CKE 4.7.1.)

(NOTE 2: Turns out you can construct a menu negatively using the `removeButtons` attribute, but I'll leave the question up as getting the entire menu as an array might still be useful.  Example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('my-region', { removeButtons: 'Save,Copy,About,Source' });
```

)

Comment: what is `default toolbar` ????

Comment: in Chrome console, entering `CKEDITOR` doesn't show this, and the only "default" under `CKEDITOR.config` is "defaultLanguage" - where would I find that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using version 4.7.1. I also have customized toolbars related to user requirements. Here is the snippet
In the config definition:

```
initToolbarSets(config);
config.toolbar = 'Default';
```

The function for building the different toolbar sets(including custom plugins):

```
function initToolbarSets(config) {
    config.toolbar_Empty = [];
    config.toolbar_Default = [
        { name: '1', items: ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'] },
        { name: '2', items: ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace'] },
        { name: '3', items: ['DataTF', 'DataCB', 'Select', 'Table', 'Image','HorizontalRule'] },
        '/',
        { name: '4', items: ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'] },
        { name: '5', items: ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'] },
        { name: '6', items: ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] },
        { name: '7', items: ['SpecialChar','PageBreak'] },
        { name: '8', items: ['Font','FontSize'] },
        { name: '9', items: ['TextColor','BGColor'] },
        { name: '10', items: ['Maximize'] }
    ];

    config.toolbar_Mail= [
        { name: '1', items: ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','Preview'] },
        { name: '2', items: ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace'] },
        { name: '3', items: ['TextField', 'Checkbox', 'Select', 'Table','Image', 'HorizontalRule', 'Link'] },
        '/',
        { name: '4', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'MyPlugin', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: '5', items: ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'] },
        { name: '6', items: ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] },
        { name: '7', items: ['SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'] },
        { name: '8', items: ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Styles'] },
        { name: '9', items: ['TextColor','BGColor'] },
        { name: '10', items: ['Maximize'] }
    ];
    config.toolbar_Helpdoc= [
        { name: '1', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'Preview'] },
        { name: '2', items: ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace'] },
        { name: '3', items: ['Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Link'] },
        '/',
        { name: '4', items: ['Bold', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'MyPlugin', 'Superscript', 'RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: '5', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent'] },
        { name: '6', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
        { name: '7', items: ['SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'] },
        { name: '8', items: ['Styles']},
        { name: '9', items: ['Maximize'] }
    ];

    //...some other toolbar profiles
};
```

Now it depends on you how to continue. Either you develope a logic (probably within the config) to decide which toolbar profile has to be shwon to the current user. Another approach could be a control that encapsulates the whole CKEditor. In my case (ASP.NET) the editor is embedded like this:

```
<mynamespace:MyHTMLTextEditor ID="ckE" runat="server" Toolbar="Helpdoc" StylesSet="helpdoc" ForcePasteAsPlainText="true"/>
```